# How to dynamically change fragment in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have created 6 fragments. First 3 fragments will load in viewPager at morning time and other 3 fragment will come in evening time. How to dynamically update the viewPager with the desired set of fragments according to time ? Here is my MainActivity code. I have implemented the first 3 fragments in the viewPager. But how to load the other 3 fragments in the viewPager ?

MainActivity:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // adding bottom dots
        addBottomDots(0);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                MyFragmentInterface fragmentInterface = (MyFragmentInterface) mSectionsPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, position);
                if (fragmentInterface != null) {
                    fragmentInterface.fragmentBecomeVisible();
                    Log.e("PageSelected", position + "");
                }
                addBottomDots(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            switch (position) {
                case 0: {
                    return new Fragment1();
                }
                case 1: {
                    return new Fragment2();
                }
                case 2: {
                    return new Fragment3();
                }
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return totalTabs;
        }
    }
```

How to load the other 3 fragments at evening time ?

UPDATE:
Looking after the solutions one issue I think will arise. What if the user is using the application since morning. Will the fragments get updated at 12:05PM at realtime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code

```
switch (position) {
case 0: {
  if(condition){
    return new FragmentOther1();
  }
  return new Fragment1();
}
case 1: {
  if(condition){
    return new FragmentOther2();
  }
  return new Fragment2();
}
case 2: {
 if(condition){
   return new FragmentOther3();
 }
  return new Fragment3();
}
```

And calculate your EVENING condition as your time slot.

For Real time add Receiver

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)){
            //notify adapter data from here. and also check time logic. this method will call for every minute.
        }
    }
};
```

In onCreate

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

and in onDestory

```
 if (receiver != null) {
  unregisterReceiver(receiver);
  receiver = null;
}
```

Comment: Even I feel the same. Will that be the efficient solution ?

Comment: This one looks more neat. But what if the user is using the application since morning and at 12:01pm what will happen ? will the fragment change realtime ?

Comment: For the real time implement BroadcastReceiver for Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED and notifyDataSetChanged of adapter.

Comment: This one is neat and I have got a good idea related to your answer. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 3):

You Can do something like this given that the next continuous number are the evening fragments.

```
switch (position) {
            case 0: {
                if (time != Calendar.AM){
                    return new Fragment4();
                }
                else {
                    return new Fragment1();
                }
            }
            case 1: {
                if (time != Calendar.AM){
                    return new Fragment5();
                }
                else {
                    return new Fragment2();
                }
            }
            case 2: {
                if (time != Calendar.AM){
                    return new Fragment3();
                }
                else {
                    return new Fragment6();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This one looks more neat. But what if the user is using the application since morning and at 12:01pm what will happen ? will the fragment change realtime ?

Comment: @SagarSuri it won't. You need a thread that actually that drastically will change the view if it's PM.

Comment: @SagarSuri  If you get time just inside `switch` then it will detect and reflect when user change page. Or if user is stay on same page for that condition use alarm manager and in receiver of that try to exit application or just reload fragment.

Comment: can you provide some more detail on it. I am confused on how to reload the fragments using broadcast receiver.

Comment: @SagarSuri you might want to read the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html or if you want some codes to follow through take a look at this, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html.

Answer (score 1):

add dynamic fragment count set

```
@Override
public int getCount() {

    // check calendar session.
    if(morning == true) {
    // Show 3 total pages morning.
        return 3;
    }else{
    // Show 3 + 3  6 total pages evening.
        return 6;
    }
}
```

then add fragments

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
    switch (position) {
        case 0: {
        return new Fragment1 ();
    }
        case 1: {
        return new Fragment2 ();
    }
        case 2: {
        return new Fragment3 ();
    }
        case 3: {
        return new Fragment4 ();
    }
        case 4: {
        return new Fragment5 ();
    }
        case 5: {
        return new Fragment6 ();
    }
    }

    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you have to make it so complicated? Create 2 lists: a list for day and a list for night. Check the time and `setAdapter` or `notifyDataSetChanged()` base on your condition

```
private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragmentList) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
    }

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void setFragmentList(List<Fragment> fragmentList) {
        this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return fragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

Here is how to implement that

```
    List<Fragment> mDayFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    mDayFragments.add(Fragment1);
    mDayFragments.add(Fragment2);
    mDayFragments.add(Fragment3);

    List<Fragment> mNightFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    mNightFragments.add(Fragment4);
    mNightFragments.add(Fragment5);
    mNightFragments.add(Fragment6);

    SectionsPagerAdapter mAdapter;

    if (yourCondition) {
        mAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(mDayAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(mNightAdapter);
    }

    yourViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Time moving... The night comes...
    mDayAdapter.setFragmentList(mNightFragments);
```

Comment: `mDayAdapter.setFragmentList(mNightFragments);` I didnt understand this line

Comment: I create a function in `SectionPagerAdapter` named `setFragmentList` to asign `List<Fragment>` with new value and notify adapter to re-update view inside ViewPager. @SagarSuri

Comment: Great Answer bro. But for some reasons i think broadcast Receiver works well